# How to Hide Text Using PHP or jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a script code to upload photos on imgur using AJAX. But I can not hide the Client-ID of the public.

I think I need to use PHP to do that use this code:

```
<?php $idClient = "abc12abc12abc";
        echo $idClient ;
?>
```

But it turned Client-ID is still visible when in view its source code.

Here's the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Imgur Upload Test</title>
        <style>
            #image_preview, #image_preview_2 {
                max-width: 200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Imgur Upload Test</h1>
        <input type="file" id="image_selector" />

        <div id="image_preview"></div>
        <h2>Image On Imgur:</h2>
        <div id="image_preview_2"></div>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#image_selector").change(function() {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    var data = e.target.result.substr(e.target.result.indexOf(",") + 1, e.target.result.length);
                    $("#image_preview").html("<img src='" + e.target.result + "' />");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
                        headers: {
                            'Authorization': 'Client-ID <?php $idClient = "abc12abc12abc";
                            echo $idClient ;?>'
                        },
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            'image': data,
                            'type': 'base64'
                        },
                        success: function(response) {
                            $("#image_preview_2").html("<img src='" + response.data.link + "' />");
                        }, error: function() {
                            alert("Error while uploading...");
                        }
                    });
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What's the solution?

Comment: Hit  your php script from ajax and then hit to imgur with auth headers from your php script.

Comment: It is still visible though if you check the requests in the console. And that is because you need it at the client side... So no matter what you do it will always be visible somehow.

Comment: @BasvanStein No, if the php script calls the API with curl for example, it's not visible to the client. I do something similar in my current project with http://guzzlephp.org (which uses curl)

Comment: Yes ok, if you add the Client id to the php script only, true.

Comment: ALL - Means there is no way to hide the Client-ID of the public?